# problem with contract instantiation

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

in the browser (I use nodejs with web3 and testrpc), I have:

```
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
```

I have the following error:

```
TypeError: web3.eth.Contract is not a constructor
```

if I use a non capitalized "c"

```
var contract = new web3.eth.contract(abi);
```

I have:

```
contract: {
  "eth": {},
  "abi": [
    {
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "displayMessage",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "payable": true,
      "type": "constructor"
    }
  ]
}
```

but later in my script:

```
var deployed = contract.new({
      from: account1,
      value: web3.toWei(3, 'ether'),
      data: bytecode,
      gas: gasEstimate,
      gasPrice: web3.eth.gasPrice
    }, (error, result) => { });
```

I have another error:

```
TypeError: this.eth.sendTransaction is not a function
```

Any idea of what is my problem ?

Comment: I do not see the line that creates the error `this.eth.sendTransaction`, did you paste all of your script?

Comment: Have you tried `var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi);` (no new) ?